# Get Azure Dashboard data via api

Tags: azure

Scenario:
One team had built one application, and application is running on azure.
maintenance is taken care by same team, we don't want to give full access of production instance to developer team, but want to give read permission, like - monitoring of logs, cpu usages etc.

Solution according to me is build an application which will get dashboard data and log data from azure via api and that data will be displayed to development team.

I am referring these 2 links
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn722415.aspx 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/api-management-get-started/

Question:

1. Still I am not able to find api which will give the dashboard data. if anyone know api for the same, please help.
2. Is there any alternative solution for this scenario.

[image: Please find image here]

Comment: What dashboard data are you referring to, in question 1 above? Can you please edit your question and clarify?

Comment: @DavidMakogon please check this image..

Answer (score 2):

If you deploy your app using the new Azure Resource Manager mode, it provides a Role Based Access Control to your resources. You can deploy your app inside a Resource Group and provide read access to your developers. They will be able to view the information about the services that your app are made of but without the option to change anything.

This session from Build 2015 can help you to understand what ARM is and what you can do with it: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-659